# Whats is the difference between 'Settings.job' and 'TimerTrigger' in Azure WebJobs SDK 3.0

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

There are many tutorials using the following code to create a Webjobs via the WebJob SDK 3.0 library.  Specifically 'TimerTrigger'

```
    public void DoSomethingUseful([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *", RunOnStartup = false)] TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
    {
        // Act on the DI-ed class:
        string thing = _usefulRepository.GetFoo();
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} - {thing}");
    }
```

The above example should run this method as a webjob every 1 minute. However this doesn't work.

I have managed to get the webjob to work when including a setting.job file.

```
setting.job: {  "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *" }
```

My question is what is the different between these two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update:

Please go to the azure webjobs log, then you can see it actually runs as per the timerTrigger defined by SDK(even though the Schedule is n/a, and settings.job is blank, it does not matter):

[image]

In short, When using webjob sdk 3.x, you can use `TimerTrigger` attribute to run the function as per the time you defined. Without using webjobs SDK(like use .zip file or publish a console project from visual studio), you can use setting.job to defined timer instead of `TimerTrigger` attribute.

1.When you're using webjobs SDK 3.x for timer trigger, you should add this line of code: `config.AddTimers();` .

Here are my code using webjobs SDK 3.x(it's a .net core 2.2 console project created in visual studio):

The packages with latest version: `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` / `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions` / `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console`

The code in Program.cs:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureWebJobs(config =>
                {
                    config.AddTimers();
                    config.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
                {
                    b.AddConsole();
                }
                )
                 .Build();

            builder.Run();
        }
    }
```

Then create a new file, like SayHelloWebJob.cs, and code in it:

```
    public class SayHelloWebJob
    {
        public void ProcessCollateFiles([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *", RunOnStartup = false)]TimerInfo timerInfo,TextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("hi, it is a testing running");
            Console.WriteLine("test");
        }
    }
```

Note that in the appsettings.json file, add your storage connection string, like below:

```
{
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
}
```

Then run the project, you can see the function is triggered as per 1 minute:

[image]

2.For settings.job, eg. if you're just creating a console project, and does not use the webjobs sdk. Since you're not using webjobs sdk, you cannot use the timerTrigger attribute. At this moment, you can include the settings.job file(in it's property, set "Copy to Output Directory" as "copy if newer") in this project and configure the scheduled timer like you did in your post. After publish as webjob(from visual studio, when publish, select "Webjob run mode" as "run on demand"), it can run as per the schedule you defined in settings.job.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I copied your code which is identical to my original code. However when publishing the web job, it appears in the azure website but the schedule is 'N/A' and no folders in blob storage are created.  Running locally it works fine.   What I find strange is the SDK actually generates a blank settings.job file on publish and the only way the job works is if I add a schedule to this file. (SDK version 3.04)

Comment: @JasonClark, do you add appsettings.json file(add AzureWebJobsStorage and it's value) and right click the file -> set "copy to output directory" as "copy if newer"?

Comment: @JasonClark, I just publish it to azure, the package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs I'm using is 3.0.8. Yes, after publish to azure, the settings.job file is blank and the schedule is N/A, but when you go to the azure webjobs log, you can see it's running as scheduled by SDK. I will update the answer with the screenshot.

Comment: Yes I have this configuration.  I did manage to get the webjob to work when publishing the job as 'Continuous' rather than triggered.

Comment: @JasonClark, it actually run as per the timeTrigger defined by SDK, please go to the webjobs log for details. And I also update my answer, you can see it's run as per schedule(even though the Schedule is n/a, and settings.job is blank, it does not matter).

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with the same problem. Here is my understanding after longer research.

There are two kind of Webjobs:

- triggered
- continuous

Triggered one has to be triggered manually or can be triggered by App Service as per CRON expression schedule provided in `setting.job`. These jobs are not present in memory once not running.

Continuous one runs always, so the process exists in memory all the time. You can schedule it using Webjobs SKD `TimeTrigger` attribute.

You will also notice difference between these two Webjob types in the Dashboard.
For triggered Webjobs you will see on top level jobs runs then functions invoked and eventually invocation details.
For continuous Webjobs this will be functions invoked and eventually invocation details. Job runs are missing as this is just one long running job.

Check App Service / Process explorer under Kudu w3wp process to see Webjobs processes running.

Note that continuous and triggered Webjobs have to be started in different way in `Main` method where you provide the configuration. All comes configured when Webjob of specific type is added via Visual Studio.

This is based on WebJobs 2.x.

My recommendation is

- for periodical (e.g. once per few hours, days) jobs use triggered
  ones, job when not running will not consume resources,
- for more frequent jobs use continuous ones with TimeTrigger
  attribute, it will consume resources all the time but will not need
  extra time for start-up.